# adobe air webcam problem

Tags: air, adobe

I have been developing a simple desktop app using adobe air, html and javascript to save data to sqlite (not as, no flash builder, no flex). Is there a way that i can capture an image from my webcam and save it using these technologies ? If not what else can be done to achieve the result? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but it is absolutely not performance-friendly :) You will get enormous string-objects (bigger images = bigger strings). But I will tell you how I did it once.

First, you have to get the BitmapData from your webcam. This can be done by creating a BitmapData-object and using its draw()-function, as shown below:

```
var bmpd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(webcam.width, webcam.height);
bmpd.draw(webcam);
```

With this BitmapData, you can then call for getPixels(), which will return a ByteArray.

```
var ba:ByteArray = bmpd.getPixels();
```

This ByteArray is now ready for serialization. Since you are storing, it is best you store it as a string. This is most commonly done by Base64. You can use [this class](http://garry-lachman.com/2010/04/21/base64-encoding-class-in-actionscript-3/) to implement the base64-encoding, as shown below:

```
var baseString:String = Base64.encodeByteArray(ba);
```

The above string can be stored in your sqlite and is a string-representation of your image. The bigger the image, the longer the conversion will take.

To get the image back from your sqlite, you can use the decodeByteArray()-method of the Base64-class I gave you, in combination with a loader-object. Example is shown below.

```
var baseString = StringFromYourSQLite;
var ba:ByteArray = Base64.decodeToByteArray(baseString);

var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
imageLoader.loadBytes(ba);
stage.addChild(imageLoader);
```

And this is how you can store and retrieve images from your database.

Comment: TY Michiel.. what if i just need to store the image as jpg in folder  after renaming using timestamp and store the imagename ? can i convert bitmapdata to jpg form?

Comment: Have a look at this link, it has source code to convert bitmapdata to jpg (and the imagename is chosen by yourself). http://weblog.cahlan.com/2006/10/save-out-bitmapdata-to-jpg.html